# Set Kendo TextboxFor max length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to set max length to 5 for textbox, Can anyone please let me know how to do that.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.LstPreEmploymentWorkflowModel.MiddleInitial))
```

I tried doing

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.LstPreEmploymentWorkflowModel.MiddleInitial).Name("middlenm")

$("#firstnm").attr('maxlength','5');
```

But if I use .Name, I get null value for middle name in the controller passed in through a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you need only do this:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.LstPreEmploymentWorkflowModel.MiddleInitial)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" }).Name("middlenm")
```